# Could something like CyberBunker be legally ran in the US?

Tags: internet, business, commerce, real-property

[CyberBunker](http://cyberbunker.com) is the name of a company and Soviet-era nuclear bunker that has been converted to a datacenter in Holland. They made some news a few years ago when they were [raided by a SWAT team](http://www.cyberbunker.com/web/swat.php), but the team was unable to enter the bunker, and they faced no charges.

The company is well-known to be a haven for hackers, as they provide server and storage rental to anyone, without much prejudice, with obviously near-impenetrable physical security. Holland and some nearby countries have some relatively unique data privacy, copyright and internet-related laws, compared to many other countries, that make this feasible.

My question, though is this: what laws would prevent a company from building a practically impenetrable fortress, and host internet services from it without prejudice, in the United States?

And, are there any legal means for a company to do what CyberBunker does in the US?

Answer (score -2):

I know this is a bit late. However, it would be kind of stupid (No Offense) to try and set up a facility like CyberBunker. You legally would be required to comply with DMCA complaints, as your business (Or Company) operates in the USA. If you refuse to comply, your Internet Service provider can/ and probably will, cancel your plan. A way to get around this would be to own your own hardware. However, it still would have through a switchboard at some point or another. Even if you manage to stay online, it wouldn't be that hard for them to dig up a road and manually cut your lines. You would have a lot more success setting up a facility in Switzerland or Holland, then trying in America. (I am not a Lawyer. Best of luck)

Hope this helped

Comment: This is incorrect. The facility would not be required to comply with DMCA, only the individuals who host servers in the DC would be. An ISP canceling your plan is not nearly as much of an issue if you run your own ISP, which a large DC can afford to do. This doesn't answer the question anyway...

Comment: @forest Almost any corporation will be sending data on somebody else's lines.  They won't need an ISP in the sense of someone who provides email service and web hosting, but they'll need some connection(s) to the Internet.  Personally, I don't use ISP services except connectivity (my email is contracted from another company), but if my ISP cut me off I'd need to find another.

Comment: @DavidThornley It's true that an ISP needs to connect to their own ISP, but those tiers are far less likely to shut you down for DMCA requests...